# Unable to set ANDROID_HOME for Cordova on Windows 10

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, npm, windows-10

I am unable to set ANDROID_HOME for Cordova

My operating System Windows 10
I have installed Android studio 2.3

[image: SDK versions]

This is my Error messages.

[image: error msg]

%ANDROID_HOME% = C:\Users\umer__000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\

Answer (score 2):

1. First create a new environment variable called `ANDROID_HOME`. For me, who has installed Android Studio, the path was `C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk`.
2. Then you need to add `tools` and `platform-tools` to your `Path` variable. Use you `%ANDROID_HOME%` variable to make it dynamic.
   [image: edit environment variabels]

Comment: you have a typo there, platform-tools, not plattform-tools ;)

Answer (score 0):

Open window cmd, write:

`echo %ANDROID_HOME%`, if you cant display your android home, check your environment variables, check if `ANDROID_HOME` exists for your user.

Try in other case, downloading just the sdk from android studio page not the complete pack and link that version of sdk.

Comment: Hi...

I changed Android SDK path, downloaded and installed just SDK but still facing this error.
If i echo %ANDROID_HOME% it shows my SDK path perfectly...
And in envoironment variables ANDRIOD_HOME exists for my user but still facing this issue.

Comment: if you download the "sdk only" version, you can see this include the folder templates in tools with gradler, check the output of your sdk, and see that path checking the folder is included.